# Emberjs - Extending a custom component doesn't get added properly to a containerview

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Am I doing this wrong? I have a containerview in my view that gets a component added to it. My component is an extension of a main component. Except what seems to be added to the view's template is the main component's template. Why isn't my extended component getting added?

My JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vicojere/1/edit

Thanks if anyone can clear this up for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`templateName` is deprecated, use `layoutName` to specify the template and it should fix your issue.

```
App.UiMainComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  layoutName: "components/ui-main"
});

App.UiSubComponent = App.UiMainComponent.extend({
  templateName: "components/ui-sub"
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vicojere/4/edit

Comment: How would you do this setup with the layoutName/templateName combo then? http://emberjs.com/guides/views/adding-layouts-to-views/ If templateName is depreciated, then if you have three components that extend a main component, all three would have to have the same parent templates all impedded.

Comment: Why is templateName depreciated on the component but not on the view class?

Comment: You can use templateName on component's that extend another component, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vicojere/5/edit